# How to slash ggplot picture in shiny app?

Tags: r

I want to plot the google map just next to the sliderBar, but when I try this code, I get a huge blank space between:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     actionButton("bb","bb"),
     sliderInput("aa","aa",value=1,min=0,max=10),
     sliderInput("aa1","aa1",value=1,min=0,max=10),
     sliderInput("aa2","aa2",value=1,min=0,max=10),
     sliderInput("aa3","aa3",value=1,min=0,max=10)
   )
   ,

   mainPanel(
     plotOutput("rys")
   )
 ) 
)


server <- function (input, output){
  output$rys <- renderPlot({qmap('Europe',zoom=4)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

how to remove this blank space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default appearance for `plotOutput` is `width="100%"` and `height="400"`

If you are on a desktop, 100% is about 1200 px and since the map is square, it is limited by the smallest dimension, height=400 to 400x400

It is centered so you have a whitespace of about 400px

To fix this issue, you can either use a bigger height, for example height="1000" or set both height and width :

```
plotOutput("rys", width = "400", height="400")
```

Comment: can ya look my new post? I did this and now I have blank space above :(